# No actions in intent filter, trying to install app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-install-apk

I created a class which uses `PackageManager` to install downloaded APK files. But when I try to install one, I get the following message in `logcat`:

```
12-25 03:11:32.014: W/PackageParser(11192): No actions in intent filter at /storage/emulated/0/download/test/test.apk Binary XML file line #22
```

I use the following code to install the app:

```
case R.id.view_application_install: {
            final File apk = Util.getApk(downloadedItem.getDirectory());
            final Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apk), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

And here is part of the manifest:

```
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.catares.android"
android:versionName="@string/app_version"
android:versionCode="9">
<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RAISED_THREAD_PRIORITY" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">       
    <activity
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:name=".Main"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".application.ApplicationActivity" 
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"              
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".application.ImageViewActivity" 
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"              
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".categories.CategoriesActivity" 
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"              
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:name=".forum.ViewForumActivity"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>     
    <activity
        android:name=".latest.LatestReleasesActivity" 
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"              
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".myapplications.MyApplicationsActivity" 
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"              
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".myapplications.ViewApplicationActivity" 
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"              
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".myapplications.installed.UpdateSearchResultActivity" 
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"              
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".search.SearchActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".application.replies.RepliesActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"         
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".settings.SettingsActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".downloads.DownloadsActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".common.UpdaterService"/>
    <service android:name=".common.downloads.DownloaderService"/>
</application>  
</manifest>
```

Line 22, which shows the error in `logcat`, is:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

Comment: You will need to change `android:name="Main"` to be either ".Main" or a fully qualified package name.

Comment: @David Wasser
I did that and edited but still doesn`t work.
I have the feeling i forgot something.

Comment: This version of the manifest snippet is malformed (e.g. extra `<activity`) - is this really the version that ended up in your test.apk?

Comment: @laalto
I now provided the complete manifest, pls see edit.

Answer (score 0):

You must include action tag in all of your intent filters.
Below is one example:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

You are just defining the category for intent filters without defining the action which that Activity would handle.

Comment: Thx my code (mentioned) is located in the  android:name=".myapplications.ViewApplicationActivity" class.
Could you pls give an example how the manifest should look like?
Kinda lost here, also the icon`s of the .apk are not shown.
Thx again.